# Problem with wireless 14.04 (RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller)

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and am having trouble getting my wireless working. I've run Ubuntu desktops before, but I just can't get it working, and I'm not sure what to do.

This is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbdff000-fbdfffff memory:fbdf8000-fbdfbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 02:00:06:51:30:38
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.50 link=yes multicast=yes
```

So the `*-network UNCLAIMED` strikes me as being a problem, but I'm not sure what to do about it. Currently tethering with my phone, and hoping to stop that soon. It's almost 2am where I am so I'm going to bed, really hoping someone has some insights overnight!

This update was requested. This is `lspci -nnk`

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
(rev 06)    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
[1458:e000]     Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/668024/edit) your question with `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2` output, thanks.

Comment: The question makes no sense. The controller you posted in the title is not wireless. It is an Ethernet controller.

Comment: There is no pci wireless adapter? Is it a usb dongle?

Comment: Ya It's a usb dongle.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but there is a little light on the usb dongle that comes on and sort of flashes while I am running windows, when in ubuntu there is no light at all.

Comment: I have been doing my best to read up, but I'm not very experienced. I did find a thread that recommended compiling this information, perhaps it will be able to help someone help me:

http://pastebin.com/hQmMgCKc

Comment: You posted the script itself, not the result of running the script. May we also see: `lsusb`. Thanks.

Comment: Hey chili I actually found a thread where you solved this problem previously, and what you suggested there worked for me. Here is  a link to it for anyone who navigates here. Good luck to you!

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168426

Answer (score 2):

*-network UNCLAIMED means that you don't have the driver installed. Just try installing the linux backports. Look the following wiki and perform the steps.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

Once done, do reboot and check.

Answer (score 2):

modify `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

put these two lines at the end:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

save and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The needed driver `r8169` is installed in all recent Ubuntu versions by default. Try to load it:

```
sudo modprobe r8169
```

Does the ethernet come to life? Or is there an error? Are there any clues in the log?

```
dmesg | grep r8169
```

Once we have more details, I will edit this answer to propose a solution.

Comment: Ok I did "sudo modprobe r8169" it asked for my password. 

Then I did dmesg | grep 8169

This was the output:

[ 1571.002628] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded

[ 1571.002641] r8169 0000:07:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control

[ 1571.003343] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc9000504a000, 50:e5:49:31:e0:bf, XID 0c900800 IRQ 31

[ 1571.003346] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]

[ 1571.155353] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link down

Comment: This is dmesg | grep r8169

http://pastebin.com/N5EFvLgD

Comment: I get `can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control`

Answer (score 0):

r8169 module(aka driver)from ubuntu kernel  is loaded,but link is down in time of Your pastebin, maybe as usb wireless is inserted..

I check realtek page(03/2017), and is updated source for that driver r8168 for kernels up to 4.7 ..
Also sometimes IOMMU seetings in BIOS needs to be enabled on some motherboards for r8169,to work..
Many people use r8168,as claim more stable connection,personally i use it as it can work with IOMMU off,on one of my motherboards.

You can try automatic way to install package r8168 with

sudo apt install r8168-dkms,

if version from ubuntu repo can be inserted in your kernel(if not there is sometimes newer version on realtek page..) ,then after reboot 
you can check with

lsmod | grep 816

what driver is loaded ,and if is in use..

if that was only problem then with

ifconfig -a

you need to see, network interfaces like lo:,eth0:,wlan0:
 ..
on other side r8168 sometimes with instalation of newer ubuntu kernel will not be inserted,but r8169 will be as is part of ubuntu kernel,so then is simplest option to use r8169 for most people...

Answer (score 0):

I spent days trying to figure out why my interface wasn't working. I thought it was a driver issue, but something was blocking the DHCP server.

You can check for this by running:

```
dmesg | grep enp3s0
```

In my case, it gave the output:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 SRC=192.168.1.1
```

To fix this, run:

```
ufw allow from 192.168.1.1
```

This solved the issue.